# How to Send Text in javascript's basic auth

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, selenium

Goal:
Add text "Accepting the alert" in the textbox from javascript's basic auth dialog and then click button "OK".

Problem:
When I execute the code "driver.SwitchTo().Alert().SendKeys("Accepting the alert");" I retrieve a error message that is "Missing 'value' parameter (IndexOutOfBounds)".

Can't find a relevant answer to my problem. Tried to solve this case but it didn't go so well.

Info:
*Using Selenium for C# code

Thank you!

[image]

```
    FirefoxDriverService firefoxDriverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\\Test3", "geckodriver.exe");
    firefoxDriverService.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";


    var driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxDriverService);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/handling-alerts-using-selenium-webdriver/");
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(@onclick,'promptConfirm')]"));

    try
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

        executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException eee)
    {
        int dd = 23;

    }


    driver.SwitchTo().Alert().SendKeys("Accepting the alert");
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I'm wondering if I really understood your question and goal. Are you testing the popup that asks for the user's credential? The one that defaults to the browser popup? If so, I see no reason to test it, it works for sure, what you have to test is sending the credentials to your server.

Comment: In this context there is no username or password in the webpage "ttp://toolsqa.wpengine.com/handling-alerts-using-selenium-webdriver/"

Comment: In this context I cannot send the data "Accepting the alert" to the textbox. That is the main problem.

Comment: If you go to the webpage "http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/handling-alerts-using-selenium-webdriver/" and click on the button "Prompt Pop up" then you will understand better.